# SPMetal, Taxonomy and TaxonomyFieldValue

Tags: taxonomy, spmetal

I have a list with a taxonomy column.

I have made SPMetal classes to work with my site.

But SPMetal doesn't create the property for taxonomy column, so I have extended my class by the ICustomMapping interface:

```
    public TaxonomyFieldValue Branch
    {
        get { return _branch; }
        set
        {
            if ((value == _branch))
                return;

            this.OnPropertyChanging("Branch", _branch);
            _branch = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Branch");
        }
```

Now I have the following problem: I need to insert a new item on my list and I would like to use SPMetal:

```
        RequestItem newRequest = new RequestItem
                                      {
                                          Branch = taxonomyField,
                                          CompanyEmailAddress = txtCompanyEmail.Text,
                                          Name = txtName.Text,
                                          Phone = txtPhone.Text,
                                          RequestType = RequestType.Entry,
                                          Status = Status.SUBMITTED,
                                          Surname = txtSurname.Text,
                                          //UserIdId = usr.ID,
                                      };
```

the value for "taxonomyField" comes from the form and I don't know how can I get it from the TaxonomyWebTaggingControl.

Answer (score 1):

The TaxonomyWebTaggingControl has a property Text. This will return the value in the format Label|Guid. To get the label, the code will be like this (from the top of my head)

```
TaxonomyFieldValueCollection tagValues = new TaxonomyFieldValueCollection();
tagValues.PopulateFromLabelGuidPairs(TaxonomyWebTaggingControlName.Text);
string labelValue=tagValues[0].Label;
```